# Symfony2: How to save a session attribute as a custom field on DB, with a custom PdoSessionStorage?

Tags: php, session, symfony, pdo, session-variables

I have a custom class extending PdoSessionStorage, but I don't know how to catch attributes from the session to save them as independent fields in the database.

Other posibility is to unserialize session data in sessionWrite($if, $data) method of my custom PdoSessionStorage Class. But I don't know how to unserialize the $data string to get only data I want to.

I tried this:

```
 unserialize($data);
```

and this throw me the follow error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 82 bytes in /myserver/myapp/src/app/myBundle/myCustomPdoSessionStorage.php line 220' in /myserver/myapp/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:65 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle(8, 'unserialize() [...', '/Applications/M...', 220, Array) #1 /myserver/myapp/src/app/myBundle/myCustomPdoSessionStorage.php(220): unserialize('_symfony2|a:3:{...') #2 [internal function]: app/myBundle/myCustomPdoSessionStorage->sessionWrite('72b823b39d316dd...', '_symfony2|a:3:{...') #3 {main} thrown in /myserver/myapp/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 65

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Add the output of `var_dump($data)` to your question and as well how you serialize the data before storing.

Comment: Thanks @hakre for your quickly response!  I really want to know where Symfony Session Class do the serialization of $data and then call $pdoSessionStorageObject->sessionWrite('..id_session..', '..data_serialized..').  Like this:  On Symfony2-file-that-I-wanna-found.php  ...  `$sessId = $session->getId();  $data-as-string = $session->serialize();//The session object as string  $pdoSessionStorageObject->sessionWrite($sessId, $data-as-string);`  I want to change my custom sessionWrite method to get one more parameter. And add a custom attribute from $session to the call of this method.

Comment: If you add the var_dump this might shed some light into it. If the session contains secret data, mask it.

Comment: Ok. I want to extract the User id attribute as a independent field in my session table without encoding it. This is the var_dump($data):                            `_symfony2|a:3:{s:10:"attributes";a:2:{s:21:"_security.target_path";s:31:"http://myapp.net/app_dev.php/";s:18:"_security_frontend";s:1781:"C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":1692:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:8:"frontend";i:2;s:1647:"a:4:{i:0;O:41:"MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User":45:{s:5:"*id";s:3:"Kevin";s:16:"*passwordClear";s:3:"KevinPass";` ...continue...

Comment: ...continue...      `s:11:"*password";s:88:"9JIIg(etc)T1w==";s:7:"*salt";s:32:"22d(etc)1f";s:9:"*name";s:5:"Kevin ";(etc)...}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:1:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Rolerole";s:9:"ROLE_USER";}}i:3;a:0:{}}";}}";}s:7:"flashes";a:0:{}s:6:"locale";s:2:"en";}`   Thanks a lot @hakre for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it!

My `CustomPdoSessionStorage` Class extends the `NativeSessionStorage`, which manages the `$_SESSION` array (read, write, etc...).

So, from my class I can use `$this->read('userId')` and store it on my DB.

So thanks a lot @hakre

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function here. `unserialize` is for serialized values, but not for sessions. Even those two are close to each other, they are different.

You might be looking for the [`session_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php) function instead. Take care it unserializes into the `$_SESSION` superglobal so you might want to wrap it:

```
function unserialize_session($data) {
    $hasBuffer = isset($_SESSION);
    $hasBuffer && $buffer = $_SESSION;
    session_decode($data);
    $session = $_SESSION;
    $hasBuffer ? $_SESSION = $buffer : unset($_SESSION);
    return $session;
}
```

The counterpart is [`session_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php) which works similarly.

See also: [How to unserialize session data in a custom handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875961/how-to-unserialize-session-data-in-a-custom-handler)

Comment: Thanks @hakre that could be a solution to my problem but I don't want to unserialize the complete session string to get only a integer (the userId). Instead of that I would like to find the place where Symfony does:  `$pdoSessionStorageObject->sessionWrite($sessId, $sessSerialized)` and replace it to `$pdoSessionStorageObject->sessionWrite($sessId, $sessSerialized, $userId)`. That way I could send the $userId as plain integer to $pdoSessionStorage object, which later will store that value in Session table on my DB as a separate field.
Sorry if I've before done a too abstract question

Comment: You probably won't have any luck with that if Symfony2 makes use of the standard PHP write handler: `write(string $sessionId, string $data)` - it has the encoded string already. You need to locate that part in the Symfony2 codebase and then look into there if that is the case or not.