# How to unserialize session data in a custom handler

Tags: php, session

I have used `sessionHandlerInterface` to save the session in database. Everything works fine. but I want to get all the serialized data from the database like

```
SELECT data FROM session;
```

and want them to decode the data when i output those.
i have tried using `session_decode()` which is manipulating `$_SESSION` array itself which is causing trouble. I just want to get the serialized data and return the decoded data.

This is the sample session data saved in database in `data` column

> fb_422782977793963_code|s:216:"AQAVKa4Q8sOuioW75V9Ls-cDUEizgJDX5ZkRVLArDlroFvvhasdwKvbyzKEwiMVrN7nc5ghMaw0W67jQu5kt_sc_Edm9sABzB5PakdkUpXr52AViTOltPfPBQHM9T-JoGOQ4gasdbssC8Xt93NKFvdV7XRZ7ZYGZqIsu5SFpfFBHK_hNGDdRVbnbe_xUZVP9WI4h0jDy";fb_422782977793963_access_token|s:111:"AAAGAhasdaAKL7hAvXRv6FHUj1Tk24r7j4NqDwWWUzmXDZA2Igsb1pHjuP4jbBRNKfeYzutm0MFmgxuKPg1n0NEbvZAXM3bwoNZBiZCgZDZD";fb_422782977793963_user_id|s:15:"100004835469598";picture|s:61:"http://m-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/sdIqmHJn-SK.gif";

It works fine with normal session handling, it reads and writes session to database as it should.

I want to get all the data of active sessions. if i use SELECT data FROM sessions. it returns the above session data(encoded) i want to get the decoded data of it.

Comment: This makes no sense in its current for. What do you want to "decode" from where and what doesn't work for you? Are you talking about character sets? If so, what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: @Pekka I have made an edit. please see It

Comment: Are you looking for http://php.net/unserialize ?

Comment: @Pekka I have tried using unserialize() but it throws error. It looks like session serialize is done in different way that serialize()

Comment: It looks like serialized data though. Maybe the data is truncated because the column is too short or something?

Comment: @Pekka yes it looks like that,I dont understand why unserialize() don't work. when i dump $_SESSION it shows all the data inside it. If it broke the string, it would not show the data.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) functions can not be used to serialize and unserialize session data. Even if (by default - and only by default) the serialization might look similar, there is an important difference to those two functions that care about a single variable contents *only*:

> Those [sessions] are a list of serialized values with their variable name.

(*from:* [Serialized README](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/blob/master/README#L26))

So you would need to create your own a `session_unserialize` function that is able to decode the string (e.g. via [`session_decode`](http://php.net/session_decode)) which is returned from your database. Take care that this needs everything in there, e.g. if the session contains serialized objects, the class definitions needs to be loaded.

An exemplary `session_unserialize` function could look like (*adopted from:* [a session related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12930902/367456)):

```
function unserialize_session($data) {
    $hasBuffer = isset($_SESSION);
    $hasBuffer && $buffer = $_SESSION;
    session_decode($data);
    $session = $_SESSION;
    $hasBuffer ? $_SESSION = $buffer : unset($_SESSION);
    return $session;
}
```

Comment: I have same problem in which i am using a custom session handler interface class "My_Core_SessionHandler_Database" in which i have defined all functions like open, close, read, write, destroy and gc. My session is being saved into database. But when i print $_SESSION after session_start() which is defined in _initSession method of /application/Bootstrap.php of Zend Framework, then i don't get complete array of session data that is being returned by "read" method. Should i write "unserialize_session" in my Class and it would automatically decode session data?

Comment: @neeraj: This answer is not about a custom session handler interface class.