# Unserializing php session data from db table

Tags: php, session

I have a custom session handler to handle session in a db table. Its working perfectly, the problem is I am unable to unserialize the contents back.

As someone pointer here [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914744/symfony2-how-to-save-a-session-attribute-as-a-custom-field-on-db-with-a-custom/12930902#12930902) to use `session_decode($data)`,but this does not seems to be working.

```
function getSession($data)
{       
    $backup = $_SESSION;        
    session_decode($data);
    $session=$_SESSION;
    $_SESSION = $backup ;
    return $session;
}
```

What I am trying is looping through session table records and decoding each of them one by one to extract some information from session.

I dont have any custom serialization for session handler , it default whatever its. Now the question is how to extra data from serialized session string ?

`php version 5.4+`

**Edit:**
  I do not have custom session serialize handler as `ini_get('session.serialize_handler')` gives me `php`, which default.

**Edit:** So far so good [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#108037) seems to be working

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function unserialize($session_data) {
        $method = ini_get("session.serialize_handler");
        switch ($method) {
            case "php":
                return self::unserialize_php($session_data);
                break;
            case "php_binary":
                return self::unserialize_phpbinary($session_data);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported session.serialize_handler: " . $method . ". Supported: php, php_binary");
        }
    }

    private static function unserialize_php($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }

    private static function unserialize_phpbinary($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            $num = ord($session_data[$offset]);
            $offset += 1;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
<?php
Session::unserialize(session_encode());
?>
```

Comment: One of the worst thing on this site is down-vote without any explanation. Which is not constructive

Comment: @shaddy check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using custom session handler. How does it writes data to database? Why don't you try with simple serialize/unserialize functions?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: probably this should be a comment

Comment: It is a solution, unless you post the code of your session handler. You can not expect more accurate answer until then.

Comment: please see my edits , I am using custom session handler not `custom session serializer`

Comment: Yes each custom session handler implement following pattern http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php So you handler has write function and close function one of them saves data to the database.

Comment: yes I known that, check this http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.read.php `Note that the serialization scheme is not the same as unserialize() and can be accessed by session_decode(). `